# Deprecated functions in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, deprecated

There are lots of functions in magento 2  which are deprecated like Registry. Can anyone give me list of such functions or classes.

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/contributor-guide/backward-compatible-development/#php

This may be helpful